# Banner not displaying CSS

Tags: css, banner

I have the following code to display a banner in my CSS stylesheet.

```
#banner {
    background-image: url(../Images/banner.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    border: 5px solid #dedede;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The banner is not displaying. Instead I get a small white cube in the top left hand corner.

The full CSS style sheet is:

```
body {
    font-family: lucida grande,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

body p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1.28;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1080px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #dedede;
}

#banner {
    background-image: url(../Images/banner.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    border: 5px solid #dedede;
    height: 200px;
}

#content_area {
    float: left;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
    clear: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
 }

footer {
    clear: both;
    width: auto;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #333;
    background-image: url(../Images/banner.jpg);
}

#navigation {
    height: 60px;
    border: 3px solid #E3E3E3;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em #333;
    background-image: url(../Images/footer.jpg);
}

#nav {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: none;
}

#nav li {
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
}

#nav a:link, nav a:active, nav a:visited {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: lightblue;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id=banner">
    </div>
    <nav id="navigation">    
         <ul id="nav">
             <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>   
             <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>    
             <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>       
        </ul>   
    </nav>    
    <div id="content_area">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <footer>
        <p>All rights reserved</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your HTML as well.

Comment: You'd used a relative URL. What is the URL of the page you are trying to display the banner on, and what is the URL of your CSS stylesheet? You'll need to share both of those for us to be able to answer your question. And have you remembered to actually upload your image to the server?

Comment: Did you try adding width to the banner?

Comment: Displaying in localhost:8080 from htdocs project folder. Image has been uploaded to the images folder in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a double quotation marks error in the id attribute value

```
<div id=banner">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:
 1. Try doing `background-repeat: repeat;` ... see what happens. 
 2. right click on the small image and click view image to confirm that the image is the right one.
 3. post the html for better understanding.